# facebook application description & logo/image

Tags: php, facebook, fbml, facebook-fbml

is it possible to return Facebook Application Description & Logo/Image just like we can return Application Name using

```
<fb:application-name />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using [fql.query](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/)